# How to reference outer object's property?

Tags: kotlin, object, scope, companion-object

Consider the following code:

```
class SomeClass {

    companion object {
        val str = "My String"
        object AnotherObject {
             fun foo(str: String) {
                  return str + //companion object's str
             }
        }
    }
}
```

How to reference `SomeClass::companion object::str` from `AnotherObject::foo`?

Comment: Use a different name for your `foo` parameter so it doesn't shadow the outer `str`?

Comment: @Bergi Unfortunately It's not possible for some internal reason

Comment: Just do `SomeClass.str`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try as follows:

```
class SomeClass {
    companion object {
        val str = "My String"
        object AnotherObject {
            fun foo(str: String): String {
                return str + SomeClass.str
            }
        }
    }
}
```